# Algolia_search on nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I got a `User` model, which has many `Skills` though his `Masteries`.

I'm using a form to retrieve users, with Algoliasearch, and I would like to retrieve all users that have a particular skill (I.E, if I got a user called "John", which has the "Origami" skill, he should appear in results if I type "John" or "Origami")

I tried to do so by mapping the nested skills, but this doesn't seem to work

Here's the model

```
class Creator < ActiveRecord::Base
include AlgoliaSearch


algoliasearch do
  # all attributes will be sent
  add_attribute :creator_skills
end

has_many :masteries
has_many :skills, through: :masteries

def creator_skills
  self.masteries.map do |s|
    { name: s.skill.name }
  end
end

[...]
```

The form returns a `query` param, which is used to retrieve creators with

```
  @creators = Creator.where(display_index: true).algolia_search(params[:query]).shuffle
```

Did I miss something ? Is it possible to map a nested model ?

Comment: The documentation explains how to achieve that : https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails#nested-objectsrelations

Comment: @MrYoshiji I tried, it seems like this doesn't work with ```has_many_though``` relationships

Comment: This post might help https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to combine both `.where` clauses and the `algolia_search` method. Also, you should rather use the faceting feature to filter on skills. That could look like:

```
class Creator < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AlgoliaSearch

  algoliasearch do
    add_attribute :creator_skills

    attributesForFaceting ['creator_skills', 'display_index']
  end

  has_many :masteries
  has_many :skills, through: :masteries

  def creator_skills
    # array of skill names
    self.skills.map(&:name)
  end

  [...]

end

# empty query (= match all) + facet filters
Creator.algolia_search('', filters: 'creator_skills:Origami AND display_index:true')
```